# Помогите с реализацией выезжающего меню

Tags: html, jquery, css3

Проблема в том, что при нажатии на крестик (fa-times) класс menu_btn обратно не появляется, подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать данную проблему

```js
$('.menu_btn').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_active');
})
$('.fa-times').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').toggleClass('menu_closed');
})

function myClick() {
  document.getElementById("menu_btn").style.display = "none";
};

function myClick1() {
  document.getElementById("fa-times").menu_btn.style.display = "fixed";
};
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #000;
  transition: 1s all ease;
  transform: translateX(100%);
  z-index: 99;
}

.menu_active {
  transform: translateX(0%);
}

.menu_closed {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.btn_fixed {
  transform: translateX(100%);
}

.menu_list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: left;
  height: 50%;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 40px 30px;
}

.menu_btn {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFF;
  width: 300px;
  background: #000;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  left: -120px;
  top: 10px;
  z-index: 99;
  background: #000;
  justify-content: space-around;
  font-family: 'Titillium Web', sans-serif;
}

.menu_btn p {
  padding-top: 6px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #78D77C;
}

#navigation {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #78D77C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.13em;
  padding-top: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.fa-times {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 7px;
  color: #FFF;
}

.fa-times:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.menu_list a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  letter-spacing: 0.05em;
  font-family: 'Libre Baskerville', serif;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

#menu_descr {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #414141;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 30px;
}

.soc_net i {
  color: #414141;
  margin-right: 20px;
  margin-left: 3px;
}

.soc_net i:hover {
  color: #FFF;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="menu">
    <a href="#" id="menu_btn" class="menu_btn" onclick="myClick()">
      <p>MENU</p><i class="fas fa-bars fa-2x "></i></a>
    <nav class="menu_list">
      <p id="navigation">navigation</p>
      <i id="fa-times" class="fas fa-times" onclick="myClick1()"></i>
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a href="#">About</a>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
      <a href="#">Works</a>
      <a href="#">Cliens</a>
      <a href="#">Contacts</a>
      <p id="menu_descr">Perspiciatis hic praesentium nesciunt. Et neque a dolorum voluptatem porro iusto sequi veritatis libero enim. Iusto id suscipit veritatis neque reprehenderit.</p>
      <div class="soc_net">
        <i class="fab fa-twitter fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-instagram  fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-facebook  fa-2x"></i>
        <i class="fab fa-vk  fa-2x"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит display="fixed" ? Бывает inline, inline-block, block, flex, inline-flex, grid а fixed нету

Answer (score 1):

Потому что в `function myClick()` ты скрываешь `display:none` элемент `#menu_btn`, а обратно не меняешь свойство `display`

Comment: Спасибо, помогло